# 少し難解な日本語：「特別な削除を使用し」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの以下のページで、「特別な削除を使用し」という日本語の一文が難解と感じました。

ページ：
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

原文：

> In such cases, the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user.

現在の日本語：

> このような場合、スタッフは票を保持する特別な削除を使用し、そのユーザーが投票した人の信用度は変化しません。

日本語案：

```
 このような場合、スタッフは特別な方法を使用して、投票を残したままユーザーを削除します。 
 その結果、そのユーザーに投票された人の信用度は変化しないことになります。
```

Answer (score 1):

適用しました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

> この削除は、ユーザーが非常に高い信用度スコアを持っていた場合を除き、ユーザーが削除されると必ず行われます。信用度の高いユーザーは、通常非常に多数の投票を行うため、それらを削除することは他のユーザーにとって破壊的な場合があります。このような場合、スタッフは特別な方法を使用して、投票を残したままユーザーを削除します。その結果、そのユーザーに投票された人の信用度は変化しないことになります。